# Migrating from RabbitMQ to Kafka and encountering possible issue with Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-sleuth

Given the example code, I'm encountering the following exception when I uncomment the `spring-cloud-sleuth-stream` dependency:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'foo' for method parameter type [class java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:100) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:103) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:360) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:271) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$200(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:63) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:372) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:352) ~[spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:792) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2100(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:246) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Test by sending a GET request to `http://localhost:8090/to_uppercase/stuff` and be sure to set the `foo` and `bar` headers.

**Gateway class**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.HeaderEnricherSpec;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableBinding({GatewayApplication.GatewayChannels.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

  interface GatewayChannels {

    String TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY = "to-uppercase-reply";
    String TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST = "to-uppercase-request";

    @Input(TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
    SubscribableChannel toUppercaseReply();

    @Output(TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
    SubscribableChannel toUppercaseRequest();

    String TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY = "to-lowercase-reply";
    String TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST = "to-lowercase-request";

    @Input(TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY)
    SubscribableChannel toLowercaseReply();

    @Output(TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST)
    SubscribableChannel toLowercaseRequest();
  }

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface StreamGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = ENRICH_TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST,
        replyChannel = GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
    String toUppercase(@Payload String payload, @Header(name = "foo") String foo,
        @Header(name = "bar") String bar);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = ENRICH_TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST,
        replyChannel = GatewayChannels.TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY)
    String toLowercase(@Payload String payload, @Header(name = "foo") String foo,
        @Header(name = "bar") String bar);
  }

  private static final String ENRICH_TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST = "enrich-to-uppercase-request";

  private static final String ENRICH_TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST = "enrich-to-lowercase-request";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow toUppercaseEnricherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ENRICH_TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
        .enrichHeaders(HeaderEnricherSpec::headerChannelsToString)
        .channel(GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow toLowercaseEnricherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ENRICH_TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST)
        .enrichHeaders(HeaderEnricherSpec::headerChannelsToString)
        .channel(GatewayChannels.TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST).get();
  }


  @RestController
  public class UppercaseController {
    @Autowired
    StreamGateway gateway;

    @GetMapping(value = "/to_upper/{string}",
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> toUpper(@PathVariable("string") String string,
        @RequestHeader("foo") String foo, @RequestHeader("bar") String bar) {
      return new ResponseEntity<String>(gateway.toUppercase(string, foo, bar), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/to_lower/{string}",
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> toLower(@PathVariable("string") String string,
        @RequestHeader("foo") String foo, @RequestHeader("bar") String bar) {
      return new ResponseEntity<String>(gateway.toLowercase(string, foo, bar), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  }

}
```

**Gateway application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          headerMode: headers
        producer:
          headerMode: headers
      bindings:
        to-uppercase-request:
          destination: to-uppercase-request
          producer:
            required-groups: stream-to-uppercase-request
        to-uppercase-reply:
          destination: to-uppercase-reply
          group: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
        to-lowercase-request:
          destination: to-lowercase-request
          producer:
            required-groups: stream-to-lowercase-request
        to-lowercase-reply:
          destination: to-lowercase-reply
          group: gateway-to-lowercase-reply
      kafka:
        binder:
          headers: replyChannel,foo,bar,Authorization,spanId,spanTraceId,spanSampled,spanProcessId,spanParentSpanId,spanName,spanFlags,messageSent
server:
  port: 8090
```

**Gateway pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**CloudStream class**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

@EnableBinding({CloudStreamApplication.CloudStreamChannels.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudStreamApplication {

  interface CloudStreamChannels {

    String TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY = "to-uppercase-reply";
    String TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST = "to-uppercase-request";

    @Output(TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
    SubscribableChannel toUppercaseReply();

    @Input(TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
    MessageChannel toUppercaseRequest();

    String TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY = "to-lowercase-reply";
    String TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST = "to-lowercase-request";

    @Output(TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY)
    SubscribableChannel toLowercaseReply();

    @Input(TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST)
    MessageChannel toLowercaseRequest();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CloudStreamApplication.class, args);
  }

  @StreamListener(CloudStreamChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
  @SendTo(CloudStreamChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
  public Message<?> processToUppercase(Message<String> request, @Header("foo") String foo,
      @Header("bar") String bar) {
    System.out.println("foo header received: " + foo);
    System.out.println("bar header received: " + bar);
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(request.getPayload().toUpperCase())
        .copyHeaders(request.getHeaders()).build();
  }

  @StreamListener(CloudStreamChannels.TO_LOWERCASE_REQUEST)
  @SendTo(CloudStreamChannels.TO_LOWERCASE_REPLY)
  public Message<?> processToLowercase(Message<String> request, @Header("foo") String foo,
      @Header("bar") String bar) {
    System.out.println("foo header received: " + foo);
    System.out.println("bar header received: " + bar);
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(request.getPayload().toLowerCase())
        .copyHeaders(request.getHeaders()).build();
  }

}
```

**CloudStream application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          headerMode: headers
        producer:
          headerMode: headers
      bindings:
        to-uppercase-request:
          destination: to-uppercase-request
          group: stream-to-uppercase-request
        to-uppercase-reply:
          destination: to-uppercase-reply
          producer:
            required-groups: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
        to-lowercase-request:
          destination: to-lowercase-request
          group: stream-to-lowercase-request
        to-lowercase-reply:
          destination: to-lowercase-reply
          producer:
            required-groups: gateway-to-lowercase-reply
      kafka:
        binder:
          headers: replyChannel,foo,bar,Authorization,spanId,spanTraceId,spanSampled,spanProcessId,spanParentSpanId,spanName,spanFlags,messageSent
server:
  port: 8091
```

**CloudStream pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudStream</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cloudStream</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you can share a project somewhere on GutHub to let us to play locally ?

Comment: See the footnotes at [the bottom of the project page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/). There are a bunch more jars that you have to override when using the kafka11 binder.

Comment: Gary, I misinterpreted your comments on the previous post. I was thinking that the dependency overrides required when including `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11` only had to be specified if they were already explicitly defined within the pom.xml files. By adding those additional dependencies, I was also able to thin out the application.yml by removing the `kafka.binder.headers` and `spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.headerMode` and `spring.cloud.stream.default.producer.headerMode` configurations.

Comment: No. Various cloud dependencyManagement pom entries bring in default versions of those jars. So you have to add rhe proper versions explicitly to your pom.

Answer (score 1):

**Gateway application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        to-uppercase-request:
          destination: to-uppercase-request
          producer:
            required-groups: stream-to-uppercase-request
        to-uppercase-reply:
          destination: to-uppercase-reply
          group: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
        to-lowercase-request:
          destination: to-lowercase-request
          producer:
            required-groups: stream-to-lowercase-request
        to-lowercase-reply:
          destination: to-lowercase-reply
          group: gateway-to-lowercase-reply
server:
  port: 8090
```

**Gateway pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**CloudStream application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        to-uppercase-request:
          destination: to-uppercase-request
          group: stream-to-uppercase-request
        to-uppercase-reply:
          destination: to-uppercase-reply
          producer:
            required-groups: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
        to-lowercase-request:
          destination: to-lowercase-request
          group: stream-to-lowercase-request
        to-lowercase-reply:
          destination: to-lowercase-reply
          producer:
            required-groups: gateway-to-lowercase-reply
server:
  port: 8091
```

**CloudStream pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudStream</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cloudStream</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka11</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```