# Spring REST Request Response with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to connect a rest endpoint Request/Response with Spring cloud stream using Spring integration gateway. The below code works for the first rest call, but subsequent calls do not work. I understand that spring cloud stream is for messaging/async operations. But this is a practical scenario where in which you need a request/response sync.

**SpringBootApplication**

```
package com.example.restgateway;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.HeaderEnricherSpec;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@EnableBinding({RestGatewayApplication.GatewayChannels.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestGatewayApplication {

  interface GatewayChannels {

    String TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY = "to-uppercase-reply";
    String TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST = "to-uppercase-request";

    @Input(TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
    SubscribableChannel toUppercaseReply();

    @Output(TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
    MessageChannel toUppercaseRequest();
  }

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface StreamGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = ENRICH, replyChannel = GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
    String process(String payload);
  }

  private static final String ENRICH = "enrich";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestGatewayApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow headerEnricherFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ENRICH).enrichHeaders(HeaderEnricherSpec::headerChannelsToString)
        .channel(GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST).get();
  }

  @RestController
  public class UppercaseController {
    @Autowired
    StreamGateway gateway;

    @GetMapping(value = "/uppercase/{string}",
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> getUser(@PathVariable("string") String string) {
      return new ResponseEntity<String>(gateway.process(string), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
  }


  @StreamListener(GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REQUEST)
  @SendTo(GatewayChannels.TO_UPPERCASE_REPLY)
  public Message<?> process(Message<String> request) {
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(request.getPayload().toUpperCase())
        .copyHeaders(request.getHeaders()).build();
  }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        to-uppercase-request:
          destination: to-uppercase-request
          group: stream-to-uppercase-request
          producer:
            required-groups: stream-to-uppercase-request
        to-uppercase-reply:
          destination: to-uppercase-reply
          group: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
          producer:
           required-groups: gateway-to-uppercase-reply
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers:
          - 192.168.34.210:9092
      default-binder: kafka


server:
  port: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do; the IntegrationFlow is sending a message directly to the input channel, bypassing the destination topic; the reply (alternately) goes out via the topic and the `replyChannel` header (required by the gateway will be lost since it's not serializable).

It will work alternately because you have 2 subscribers on the reply channel - the gateway and the binding. By default, when a channel has 2 subscribers, messages are distributed in round-robin fashion. One message will go to the gateway, the next to the binding, etc, etc.

Comment: I am trying to do the same as in this answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800497/how-can-messaginggateway-be-configured-with-spring-cloud-stream-messagechannels?rq=1

Comment: Yes; but you have the `@StreamListener` in the same application; which  is wrong since you'll have 2 subscribers on each channel - the binding and the local references.